# Passing QRadioButton value from one window to another window in Qt (no matching function for call to)

Tags: qt, qradiobutton

I want to pass selected QRadioButton's value from one Window to another. I am confused with the function declaration to accept the text value in Second Window, here is my code.

Window1.cpp

```
void SelectOS :: processNextButton(){
if(ui->win32->isChecked()){
QString loc = "WIN/32Bit";
SelectSoftware *ss = new SelectSoftware (loc);
this->hide();
ss->show();
}
else
{
//QMessageBox:warning();
}
}
```

Window2.h

```
public:
SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0);
```

Window2.cpp

```
SelectSoftware::SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent),ui(new ui::SelectSoftware)
{
QString softpath = text;
qDebug << softpath;
}
```

But when I call

```
ss = new SelectSoftware();
```

or

```
ss= new SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent);
```

in Window2.cpp, I get the error : `no matching function for call to SelectSoftware::SelectSoftware()`

Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

Window2.cpp

```
#include "selectsoftware.h"
#include "ui_selectsoftware.h"

SelectSoftware *ss;
QStringList selectedModuleList;

SelectSoftware::SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SelectSoftware)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    softpath = text;
    setWindowPosition();
    getSoftwareDetails();
    initializeUi();
}

SelectSoftware::~SelectSoftware()
{
    delete ui;
}

void SelectSoftware::setWindowPosition()
{
    QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();
    int x = (desktop->width() - size().width())/2;
    int y = (desktop->height() - size().height())/2;
    move(x, y-50);
    setFixedSize(size().width(), size().height());
}

void SelectSoftware::cancel()
{
    qApp->exit(0);
}

    void SelectSoftware::showMainPage()
    {
        ss = new SelectSoftware(softpath); // here its creating problem, not going forward and app is crashing!!!

        for(int j = 0; j < softwareList.size(); j++){
            if(checkBox[j]->isChecked()){
                if(!comboBox[j]->currentIndex()){
                    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Select version !", "Select version number for all selected software");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < softwareList.size(); i++){
            if(checkBox[i]->isChecked()){
                ss->selectedSoftList.push_back(checkBox[i]->text());
                ss->selectedVerList.push_back(comboBox[i]->currentText());
            }
        }

        if(!ss->selectedSoftList.size()){
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "No product Selected !", "Select one");
            return;
        }

    else{
            SelectionPage* sp = new SelectionPage;
            this->hide();
            sp->show();
        }
    }

    void SelectSoftware::test(const int id) 
    {
        if(checkBox[id]->isChecked()){
            comboBox[id]->setEnabled(true);
            comboBox[id]->addItem(" Select anyone ");
            QString path = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/products/" + checkBox[id]->text();

            QDir dir;
            dir.cd(path);
            dir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

            QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
                comboBox[id]->addItem(fileInfo.fileName());
            }

        }else{
            comboBox[id]->clear();
            comboBox[id]->setDisabled(true);
        }
    }

    void SelectSoftware::getSoftwareDetails()
    {
        QString fileName = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/abc/" + SOFTWARELIST;
        QFile file(fileName&#41;;
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text&#41;){
            QString msg = "Could not find the file " + fileName;
            errorExit(msg);
        }

        QTextStream in(&file);
        while (!in.atEnd()) {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            processLine(line.toLower());
        }
    }

    void SelectSoftware::processLine(QString str)
    {
        QStringList list = str.split(",");
        QDir path = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/products/" + list[0];
        if(path.exists() && (list.size() == 2)){
            QString tmp = list[0];
            tmp = tmp.toLower();
            softwareList.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    void SelectOption::initializeUi()
    {
        this->setWindowTitle("Window2");

        QGridLayout *gridLayout1 = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout1->setMargin(5);
        gridLayout1->setSpacing(5);

        QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            radioButton[i] = new QRadioButton();
            radioButton[i]->setText(softwareList[i]);
            signalMapper->setMapping(radioButton[i], i);
            gridLayout1->addWidget(radioButton[i], i/1, i%1);
            connect(radioButton[i], SIGNAL(clicked()),signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        }

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const int &)),this, SIGNAL(radioChecked(const int &)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(radioChecked(const int &)),this, SLOT(test(const int)));

        QGridLayout *gridLayout2 = new QGridLayout();
        gridLayout2->setMargin(5);
        gridLayout2->setSpacing(5);

        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
            comboBox[j] = new QComboBox();
            comboBox[j]->setDisabled(true);
            gridLayout2->addWidget(comboBox[j], j/1, j%1);
        }

        QPushButton *nextButton = new QPushButton("Next >");
        nextButton->setDefault(true);
        connect(nextButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showMainPage()));

        QPushButton *backButton = new QPushButton("< Back");
        backButton->setDefault(true);
        connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,     SLOT(showSelectOS()));

        QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton->setDefault(true);
        connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(cancel()));

        QHBoxLayout *hboxlayout;
        hboxlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        hboxlayout->addLayout(gridLayout1);
        hboxlayout->addLayout(gridLayout2);

        QHBoxLayout *layout;
        layout = new QHBoxLayout();
        layout->addStretch(10);
        layout->addWidget(nextButton);
        layout->addWidget(backButton);
        layout->addWidget(cancelButton);
        layout->addStretch(10);

        QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
        mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        mainLayout->addLayout(hboxlayout);
        mainLayout->addLayout(layout);
        ui->centralwidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    }

    QVector<QString> SelectSoftware::getSelectedSoftware()
    {
        return ss->selectedSoftList;
    }

    QVector<QString> SelectSoftware::getSelectedVersion()
    {
        return ss->selectedVerList;
    }

    QStringList SelectSoftware::getSelectedModules()
    {
        return selectedModuleList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you changed your `SelectSoftware` constructor? Can you show it? The code above should not crash in the line you marked. Though sometimes valid code, built by QtCreator crashes, because it rebuilds not all of changed object files. In order to fix that you need to rebuild your project ('Build->Clean All' + 'Build->Run qmake' + 'Build->Rebuild All')

Comment: @Amartel Hmm maybe.. `SelectSoftware` constructor has been updated... please check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - [use signals and slots, Luke](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

Second of all, you cannot call `ss = new SelectSoftware();`, since you haven't declared `SelectSoftware` constructor without parameters, and calling `ss= new SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent);` is illegal in C++.

`SelectSoftware *ss = new SelectSoftware (loc);` is correct, though.

Comment: Thanks again :D, I need this `loc` variable to be available in each every function definition in Window2.cpp, how can I do this??

Comment: You should make it a member of your `SelectSoftware` class. Add `QString softpath;` to a class definition in header and `softpath = loc;` in `SelectSoftware` constructor instead of `QString softpath = text;`. After that `softpath` will be available in each member of `SelectSoftware` class.

Comment: Well, now I'll tell my problem: in Window2.cpp, there is one SLOT called test(), in that test, its being defined as `ss = new SelectSoftware` , as we've provided arguments `QString &text`, I've modified to `ss = new SelectSoftware(text)`. But this is creating the problem, again its executing `SelectSoftware(text)` function, where the value of text has become empty and the application is crashing!!!

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem is, since I don't know, how you are using this string, and what your test slot is for. You should run your application with debugger and find the line of your code, where your program crashes. Then you should fix the program logic.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In `void SelectSoftware::processLine(QString str)` addressing to `list[0]` without checking that list is not empty might be dangerous. I recomend you to add:

```
if (!list.size())
    return;
```

right after initialization.

**2.** In `void SelectOption::initializeUi()` what is `list`? Are you sure `list.size() <= softwareList.size()`? If not, it's a potential problem.

**3.** What is `radioButton`? I don't see it's initialization. If it is `QList < QRadioButton * >`, than `radioButton[i] = new QRadioButton();` is a bad one and you should do this:

```
radioButton.append(new QRadioButton());
```

**4.** Same goes to `comboBox`.

Each of the list can cause the crash of your application. And I could easily miss something.

Comment: Can we pass multiple text parameter values to `SelectSoftware::SelectSoftware(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)` or we need to do like `SelectSoftware::SelectSoftware(const QString &text,const QString &path, QWidget *parent)` to pass another variable ??

Comment: Hmm.. then what is Overloading for? Can't we pass two text values to single Parameter?

Comment: Please, read the article about overloading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading . I hate to saying this, but some of your questions are described in manuals very well.